# Sharepoint 2013 delete AttachmentFiles by JS

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, attachments

how can I delete an AttachmentFiles of a list item by Javascript?
(with REST or using SP.RequestExecutor) 
Thank,Nk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REST (with [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/getItemById(1)/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName('test.txt')",
  method: 'DELETE',
  headers: {
    'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
    }
});
```

You can see the REST API endpoints at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx . And you can see the equivalent for JSOM and CSOM at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594(v=office.15).aspx . You see the one I used at the top there.

For example in the first link you know you want [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_ListItem), and then you check the [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_ListItemProperties) where you will find AttachmentFiles. Although this will not give you the `getByFileName` method you were seeking. What I did to find this was to actually use the second link above and follow the JSOM example and click methods for [SP.AttachmentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245160%28v=office.15%29.aspx#methods). I'm not sure why the documentation is lacking this, but you can usually find the same methods in JSOM as in REST (usually).
And as I knew that as long as I got some kind of item I could use the *DELETE* verb to delete it I just tried that and it worked.

Another simple approach is to simply query against the API and you will see available methods listed out for you, so just playing around with it and traversing downwards step by step helps a lot.

Comment: Where can I find a complete documentation of rest api? (With method getByFileName and so on)

Comment: Updated, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
function DeleteItemAttachment(ItemId, FileTitle) {  
            var Dfd = $.Deferred();  
            var Url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Attachments')/GetItemById(" + ItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName('" + FileTitle + "')  ";  
            $.ajax({  
                url: Url,  
                type: 'DELETE',  
                contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',  
                headers: {  
                    'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),  
                    'X-HTTP-Method': 'DELETE',  
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'  
                },  
                success: function (data) {  
                    Dfd.resolve(data);  
                },  
                error: function (error) {  
                    Dfd.reject(JSON.stringify(error));  
                }  
            });  
            return Dfd.promise();  
        }
```

Usage:

```
DeleteItemAttachment(itemId,'File Name').done(function(response){
//do something with response
})
```